# How do I call an asynchronous method from within an ASPX file (not codebehind)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, webforms

I have a DLL that contains an async method for obtaining a report. It does all the heavy lifting, including HTML formatting.

```
namespace MyReportEngine
{
    public class Renderer
    {
        static public async Task<string> GetReportHtml()
        {
            //Magic (not important)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a web site without doing a lot of work. All I want to have to do is create a simple ASPX file that uses the DLL. I tried this:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="MyAssembly" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyAssembly.MyReportEngine" %>
<%@ Page Async="true" %>

<html>
<body>
    <% =await Renderer.GetReportHtml() %>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in a runtime exception during JIT compilation:

```
Compiler Error Message: BC36937: 'Await' can only be used when contained within a method or lambda expression marked with the 'Async' modifier.
```

I've checked the documentation and tutorials like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/october/wicked-code-asynchronous-pages-in-asp-net-2-0) but they only seem to deal with adding async calls to the codebehind. There is no information on how to make the call from the ASPX markup itself. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you trying to get the page up and then load the content dynamically? You'll probably need to AJAX the content in.

Comment: No I am not trying to get the page up then load the content dynamically. I am trying to render the page completely server-side.

Comment: OK. Than this is something that is documented : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a seperate method then call that method.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid putting code in the markup.

For your use case, you can use a [Literal control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal):

```
<%@ Assembly Name="MyAssembly" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MyAssembly.MyReportEngine" %>
<%@ Page Async="true" %>

<html>
<body>
    <asp:Literal id="ReportHtml" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing `Page.RegisterAyncTask`?

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(GetReportHtml));
}
```

Ref: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx